# html.erb not rendering properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an html.erb file that does not render anything when the following is used:

```
<% form_for :profile do |form| %>
```

when this is used (note the "=" sign):

```
<%= form_for :profile do |form| %>
```

this is the output of the html:

[image: web page]

Partial html code:

```
<%= form_for :profile do |form| %>
```

```
<%= text_field_for form, "first_name" %>
<%= text_field_for form, "last_name" %>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <%= radio_button :profile, :gender, "Male" %> Male
    <%= radio_button :profile, :gender, "Female" %> Female
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="birthdate">Birthdate:</label>
    <%= date_select :profile, :birthdate,
                    :start_year => Profile::START_YEAR,
                    :end_year => Time.now.year,
                    :include_blank => true,
                    :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
</div>
```

Form_for definition:

```
def text_field_for(form, field,
                  size=HTML_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE,
                  maxlength=DB_STRING_MAX_LENGTH)
 label = content_tag("label", "#{field.humanize}:", :for => field)
 form_field = form.text_field field, :size => size, :maxlength => maxlength
 content_tag("div", "#{label} #{form_field}", :class => "form_row")
end
```

Part of controller:

```
def edit
 @user = current_user
 @user.profile ||= Profile.new
 @profile = @user.profile
 if param_posted?(:profile)
   if @user.profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    flash[:notice] = "Changes saved."
    redirect_to :controller => "users", :action => "index"
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe it should be `<%= form_for @profile do |form| %>`

Comment: already tried that with no luck :(

Comment: did you define `@profile` in your controller? `@profile = Profile.new`

Comment: yes, it is defined. added controller to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `text_field_for` helper you need to declare that the string passed as the content of your `DIV` tag  generated by your helper is safe, and thus should not be sanitized. This is done with `html_safe`.

```
def text_field_for(form, field,
  size =HTML_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE,
  maxlength =DB_STRING_MAX_LENGTH)
  label = content_tag("label", "#{field.humanize}:", :for => field)
  form_field = form.text_field field, :size => size, :maxlength => maxlength
  content_tag("div", "#{label} #{form_field}".html_safe, :class => "form_row")
end
```